# Implementing OpenID

Tags: openid

Following this tuto:

http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe

One of the steps is:

> Need to look up whether the OpenID
>   entered already belongs to an existing
>   user on your site

My problem:

what's the **OpenID** like for a gmail account(I've no other OP account yet)? It seems to me that **OpenID** = `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` for gmail, but how can I use that to look up since it's the same for all users?

Comment: The real id (the one mentioned by Dav) will be available in the `openid.claimed_id` variable of the openid response. Read http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#Samples for more info.

Comment: So the id is not for direct login, but to retrieve info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` is what you use for login. Upon a successful login, the response from Google will contain the long unique url (with hash) in the `openid.claimed_id` variable; that is the one you should store in your db and compare to know if it is a new user or an existing one.

In other openid providers like myopenid, both (login url and the claimed_id) are same.

Comment: But the tuto I posted seems to say that OpenID can be got before redirect to gmail?

Comment: The page isn't accessible here; but yeah, as I said, in the case of other providers like myopenid etc, you can get the unique id before redirection: but how can you confirm that user is not lying - you can confirm the identity only based on the response from the openid provider, be it google or myopenid.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=XXXXXXXX` for some unique string `XXXXXXXX` on the end that corresponds to the user.

From further down in the page you linked:

> When the OpenID provider redirects to
>   your return_to URL, they will add a
>   bunch of additional query string
>   parameters that contain the
>   information needed to verify the
>   user's authentication with this
>   OpenID. Depending on the OpenID
>   library you're using, you may need to
>   gather these up into a data structure
>   to pass in to the verification
>   function, or it may do it for you.

One of those is that string. From the Google OpenID documentation:

> A Google-supplied identifier, which
>   has no relationship to the user's
>   actual Google account name or
>   password, is appended as the query
>   parameter openid.claimed_id.

Comment: Does this hold: `xxxxx` = `user@gmail.com` ?

Comment: No. It holds a hash string that doesn't correspond to any particular user information, the only guarantee is that the same user will have the same hash string.

Comment: Also, you may wish to look at google's own documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html - relevant quote, "A Google-supplied identifier, which has no relationship to the user's actual Google account name or password, is appended as the query parameter openid.claimed_id."

Comment: I tried that hash string, but still have to go to gmail to sign in. Say,what's the benefit to append an additional `xxxxx` ?

Comment: Is it because of SO didn't implement this feature?

Comment: @Dav ...same user will have the same hash string for the same site - your hash strings for SO and meta.SO would be different. This is for improved privacy it seems.

Comment: @openid: "I tried that hash string, but still have to go to gmail to sign in." - you will ALWAYS need to go to gmail to sign in; that's *how OpenID works*. The signin is done by the openid provider; the reason you do it is to prevent having to create a separate login username/password for each site.

Comment: I thought the hash string is used for direct login,seems I'm wrong?

Comment: No, the hash is part of the per-user identifier. OpenID does not support direct login (and supplying repeated-use login credentials via a URI would be rather insecure).

Answer (score 1):

The key distinction here is that `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` is not an OpenID identifier, not in the way that the tutorial means.  Because, as you've noted, it's the same for all users.  In the [terminology of the specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#terminology), it is an "OP Identifier", it identifies the *provider* (Google), not a user.

This practice (entering the provider's identifier instead of the user's) wasn't common at the time *A Recipe for OpenID-Enabling Your Site* was written.  When using this flow, you don't have an identifier for the user until the user is redirected back to your site from the provider with an `id_res` response.

As an aside, Google does offer more legible identifier URLs now.  If you've set up your Google Profile, your profile page (`http://www.google.com/profiles/myProfileName`) is an OpenID too.  Unlike the `/accounts/o8/id` identifiers, this one is stable across all the sites you use it with, no funky hash string involved.